# How to perform action when auth0 Android passwordless auth is completed

Tags: android, authentication, auth0

trying to implement passwordless auth on android using auth0.

I can get auth0 to add a user/send them an using the below method:

```
.start(new BaseCallback<Void, AuthenticationException>() {
        @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void payload) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(AuthenticationException error) {

            }
        });
```

`onSuccess()` is called if the network request happens successfully (all good).

Once a user clicks on the link in the email, it opens another activity - how can I intercept either a `Credentials` object, or use `onActivityResult()` in this activity? The documentation isn't very clear!

Comment: The documentation is quite poor. Anyway, using email as a passwordless solution on mobile application, specially on android is complicated because it will loose the context, and it isn't the activity that open up an Intent, therefor you can't use `onActivityResult()`

Comment: The email contains a deeplink though which starts the relevant activity, so it's not really a problem

Comment: Are you using the lock or the auth0 library? 
I believe that something is stored in the bundle or something.